# jQuery store actual CSS background color, apply a new and then restore the original

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to notify the modified field on an AJAX petition with changing the background of `<tr />` changed but I cant get it working.

My code contains an AJAX petition but I handle this right the problem is with that:

```
var $this = $(this);
if(confirm("Delete?"))
{
    // My AJAX petition returns TRUE or FALSE, if TRUE:

    // Store the ORIGINAL color
    var ORIGINAL = $this.closest("tr.entry").css('backgroundColor');

    // The alert works fine
    alert(ORIGINAL);

    // Change the color with the desired and then change with the original after a delay.
    // If i dont use the delay() and the second css() works fine.

    $this.closest("tr.entry").css('backgroundColor','#ace997').delay(500).css('backgroundColor', ORIGINAL);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First line should read var $this = $(this);

Comment: Oups sorry! Typo error. I've well written in my .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `.delay()` method is for managing the effects queue, using jQuery effects. Since you aren't using those, you should be using `setTimeout`:

```
$this.closest("tr.entry").css('backgroundColor','#ace997');

window.setTimeout(function(e) {
    return function() {
        e.css('backgroundColor', ORIGINAL);
    }
}($this.closest('tr.entry')), 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthasis on your confirm() if statement.

`if(confirm("Delete?")`

should be

`if(confirm("Delete?"))`